# How can I validate text box input where user cant start their name with number?

Tags: php

How can I make a validation where a user can't *start* their name with number, but can use a number anywhere else?

```
if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z0-9'-]+$/",$name))
{
   $nmerror = "error found ";
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
<?php
if ( !preg_match('/^[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9]/', $name) )
{
    echo "Not valid!";  
}
else
{
 echo "Valid!"; 
}
?>
```

Comment: Your Regex is not blocking any special character in the last of string, there is not use of `[A-Za-z0-9]` last block

Comment: @jogesh_pi Question was `can't start their name with number, but can use a number anywhere else` So Just took care of required things!

Answer (score 0):

it should be :

```
if( ! preg_match( '/^[a-zA-Z]+[a-zA-Z0-9\'\-]+$/', $name ) ){
    echo "Error";
}
```

This code match Alphabets on the starting, and also validate the digits `0-9`,`'` and `-`(hyphen)

Comment: what is difference in ( !preg_match('/^[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9]/', $name) ) and ( ! preg_match( '/^[a-zA-Z]+[a-zA-Z0-9\'\-]+$/', $name ) )

Comment: @user3240577 `'/^[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9]/` or `/^[A-Za-z]/` block only check the alphabet on the start nothing else of someone pass special characters that should not be include in name, And  `/^[a-zA-Z]+[a-zA-Z0-9\'\-]+$` block check the Alphabet only in start and in the any ony digit or `'` or `-` or not.